# explicitly set a field's width in css to "no-auto"

Tags: css

In a css field, one can set a field to something like

```
.foo {width:auto;}
```

Is there something like `non-auto` that I can use to say the value should not be auto?

(The system I am working on has a bunch of css files, possibly overwriting one another, especially because of localisation, so to fix quick a bug, all I want to to unset the `auto` attribute.).

Comment: Its easy just set it to something else...you can inherit from its parent or set it to a percentage of its parent or fix it to pixel size etc.  Check http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/width

Comment: `auto` is the default value for the CSS `width` attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp). What should it be instead?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do when you set this `no-auto`? On the surface this has a very simple answer (just set a width) but I wonder if there is something more to the question.

Answer (score 4):

`auto` is the default value and it just means that the width will be calculated by the browser.

If you don't want it to be calculated automatically, the only alternative you have is to set it to a specific value in relative or absolute units (`px`, `em`, etc. or `%`). You can also use the value `inherit` to take the width from the parent, but in any case your element **must** always have a width.

The concept of 'no-auto' just means that you set the value explicitly. There are no other possible values (except for some experimental keywords, but they really just modify how the `auto` width is calculated).